# How to use string as an input value?

Tags: java

I have the task to make a program that allows the user to enter their date of birth and it will output their Chinese Zodiac animal and their astrological sign. The program thinks that the months are variables that are undeclared, but I am trying to make them values that the for the variable "month".

Here is the code,

---

```
int  day, year;
String month;

System.out.println("Enter the month you were born.");
month=in.nextLine();
System.out.println("Enter day you were born.");
day=in.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter the year you were born."); 
year=in.nextInt(); 

if (month==January && day <=20)
    System.out.println("You are a Capricorn.");
if (month==January && day > 20)
    System.out.println ("You are an Aquarius.");
if (month==February && day <= 19)
    System.out.println ("You are an Aquarius.");
if (month==February && day >19)
    System.out.println ("You are a Pisces.");
if (month==March && day <= 20)
    System.out.println ("You are a Pisces.");
if (month==March && day > 20)
    System.out.println ("You are an Aries.");
if (month==April && day <= 20)
    System.out.println ("You are an Aries.");
if (month==April && day >20)
    System.out.println ("You are a Taurus.");
if (month==May && day <= 21)
    System.out.println ("You are a Taurus.");
if (month==May && day > 21)
    System.out.println ("You are a Gemini.");
if (month==June && day <= 21)
    System.out.println ("You are a Gemini.");
if (month==June && day >21)
    System.out.println ("You are a Cancer.");
if (month==July && day <=22)
    System.out.println ("You are a Cancer.");
if (month==July && day >22)
    System.out.println ("You are a Leo.");
if (month==August && day <=22)
    System.out.println ("You are a Leo.");
if (month==August && day >22)
    System.out.println ("You are a Virgo.");
if (month==September && day <=23)
    System.out.println ("You are a Virgo.");
if (month==September && day >23)
    System.out.println ("You are a Libra.");
if (month==October && day <=23)
    System.out.println ("You are a Libra.");
if (month==October && day >23)
    System.out.println ("You are a Scorpio.");
if (month==November && day <=22)
    System.out.println ("You are a Scorpio.");
if (month==November && day >22)
    System.out.println ("You are a Sagittarius.");
if (month==December && day <=21)
    System.out.println ("You are a Sagittarius.");
else
    System.out.println ("You are a Capricorn.");
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to make your months strings by putting double quotes around them:

```
if (month.equals("January") && day <=20)
System.out.println("You are a Capricorn.");
```

Realize that the user is going to have to put in exactly "January", so "january" won't work. To achieve this, make sure you use the `toLower` function. You could also use the `equalsIgnoreCase()` as well.

Follow that same pattern for each of your months. Any time you use a string literal, it needs to be in `" "`. Also if you are comparing strings, you need to use `equals()` as shown above.

As Luiggi pointed out in the comments below, it would make more sense to do:

```
 if ("January".equals(month) && day <=20)
```

This will avoid the `NullPointerException` error that could potentially arise.

Comment: `month=="January"` is no good idea, `month.equals("January")` would work better in Java

Comment: Thanks guys. Still early, and haven't had the coffee yet ;)

Comment: @AlexShesterov in fact, a better idea is `"January".equals(month)` to avoid NPEs.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, and how can I use the toLower function?

Answer (score 1):

try like this

```
 if (month.equalsIgnoreCase("January") && day <=20)
        System.out.println("You are a Capricorn.");
```

if user types `JANUARY` or `january` it will give u good result.

Answer (score 0):

The .equals("Month") is correct but also you need to add "else" to all the if statements except the first.  Otherwise your final else will only be applied to the if before it making it proc most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

Right now Java doesn't really know what you mean by `January` it thinks your referring to some kind of variable or keyword and it has no idea.
By putting `"January"` in quotes like that your telling java hey this is a piece of text or as computers like to call it a String.
Pro tip don't compare to strings with `==` that checks if you entered the same object on both sides. Which in some situations gives you some weird results because of the way strings work in Java. So always use `myString.equals(someOtherString)` to check if two strings have the same content.